# Microsoft Recommendation API with Firebase

Tags: ios, azure, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, azure-cognitive-services

Can I use Microsoft Recommendation API with data in Firebase for iOS?

I know that I can use the Vision API with Firebase, but I don't know about the others.

Answer (score 0):

The Recommendations API has been deprecated, please see the following for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/recommendations/overview.